# Displaying Data which is stored in sqlitedatabase

Tags: android

a login page with save and display button i want to display data  which is saved in sqlite using toast...problem is in display code please help me...i post my code here...i am a beginner

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pagevalidation;
    import com.example.pagevalidation.*;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        SQLiteDatabase db;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String uname = name.getText().toString();

            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

        }

        public void savedata(View view) {

            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String uname = name.getText().toString();

            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            dh.insert(uname, pass);
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.class,"record inserted",3000).show();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void displaydata() {
            DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor c= dh.getAll();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "name: " + c.getString(1)+ "\n" + "password: " + c.getString(2),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } while (c.moveToNext());

            }
            db.close();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }



Databasehandler class for handling database 


DatabaseHandler.java


package com.example.pagevalidation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "loginManager";


    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";


    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PASS = "password";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);


      //  onCreate(db);
    }

    void insert(String name,String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); 
        values.put(KEY_PASS, password); 
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); 
    }

   /* public Cursor getAll() {
        return(getReadableDatabase()
        .rawQuery("SELECT id, name, password FROM TABLE_LOGIN",
        null));
        }*/
    public Cursor getAll()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE_LOGIN", null);

        return c;

    }


   }
```

Comment: [see the reference link](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that your are not calling displaydata() method from anywhere.

Add it at the end fo your onCreate() method:

```
onCreate(){
   ...
   displayData();
}
```

Is you are a begginer then you should take a look to documentation about how activities work, basically they have some methods and you override them to add your activity's behaviour (like onCreate()). Methods not being override (I mean, you create those methods) need to be called from somewhere.

Comment: onclick of display button I called displaydata() method  in activity_main.xml